# Katalon Analytics is not showing results of all test suites executed from Test Collection

Tags: katalon-studio

I am executing Katalon "Test Collection" which has 11 Test Suites. Katalon Studio is bound to a Project in Katalon Analytics. But Katalon Analytics is showing results of only 2 Test suites after the execution is ended from Katalon Studio. However, when the Test executions are in progress then Katalon Analytics is showing the count of test cases correctly.

Katalon Studio version: 7.6.6 Build 205
Katalon Analytics: TestOps Beta

Can anyone help me to figure out this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Problem is resolved after downgrading Katalon Studio to 7.5.5 from 7.6.6 version. Seems like Katalon Studio latest version is not supporting complete results to be posted on Katalon Analytics.